# Why does GSAP pre-rendering stop when viewWidth > 1999px

Tags: css, gsap, horizontal-scrolling, prerender

I'm working on a site that incorporates a horizontal scroller similar to what's shown in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/YzygYvM).

Only problem is that the panels begin to "jump" onto the screen when the view width is greater than 1999px. To recreate the issue, just go to the CodePen link and resize the CodePen viewport to be 2000px or greater. Then, scroll quickly through the page. You should notice that the panels will not render until the leading edge enters the screen.

Now, resize to 1999px or less, and the issue disappears. Everything looks smooth. Anyone know why/how I can fix this? It's as if once view width grows to 2000px, there is some optimization happening to avoid rendering until content enters the viewport.